# How to make dynamic getter with defineProperty in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, defineproperty

I want to define dynamic getter functions with `defineProperty` in JavaScript like below. In order to make a readonly function, I want to use `defineProperty`. This enables me to throw an Exception in the setter function.

However the getter function won't be functional. I thought that this getter returns the any properties of the `obj` dynamically. But it wasn't. It always returns `obj["three"]`, last property. Is there any methods to make dynamic getter which returns appropriate property in JavaScript?

```
var obj = {"one":1, "two":2, "three":3};
var cloned = {};

for (var prop in obj) 
{
    var getter = makeGetter(prop);
    Object.defineProperty(cloned, prop, 
    {
        set: function() 
        {
            throw new UnableRewriteException('original cannot be rewrite');
        },
        get: function() 
        {
            return obj[prop]
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
}
```

Comment: This again looks like the classic loop-closure problem, remember that `var` will be function level not block level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @paul-s mentioned you have a problem with a closure inside your loop. A simple fix:

```
var obj = {"one":1, "two":2, "three":3};
var cloned = {};

function makeReadOnlyProperty(cloned, obj, prop) {
    Object.defineProperty(cloned, prop, 
    {
        set: function() 
        {
            throw new UnableRewriteException('original cannot be rewrite');
        },
        get: function() 
        {
            return obj[prop]
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
}

for (var prop in obj) 
{
    makeReadOnlyProperty(cloned, obj, prop);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem was solved and I can obtain deep understanding of JavaScript closure. :-)